# parsing string for dropdownlist options

Tags: c#, string, parsing, split, html-select

I have a string (q.ADDLOption) with values like

```
Select,|IE,IE|Safari,Safari|Chrome,Chrome|
```

I want to parse it to be the options in a dropdownlist

```
Optionddl oddl = q.ADDLOption.Split('|').ToList<Optionddl>(); <== this is giving error
```

I have also a class

```
public class Optionddl
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: whats the error that youre getting?

Comment: and can you supply us with more code, as this isn't really a lot to help you, what is q ?

Comment: Use `List<Optionddl> oddl = q.Trim(' ', '|').Split('|').Select(x => new Optionddl { text = x.Trim().Split(',')[0], value = x.Trim().Split(',')[1] }).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the trick for you

```
List<Optionddl> oddl = q.ADDLOption.Split(new string[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                       .Select(x => new Optionddl
                       {
                           text = x.Split(',')[0],
                           value = x.Split(',')[1]
                       })
                       .ToList<Optionddl>();
```

The first problem with the code is `q.ADDLOption.Split.ToList` is going to return a list and not an object of `Optionddl`. Secondly we cannot directly convert an array of string[] to List because 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments would be the error. Lastly it is optional to create `ToList` or `ToList<Optionddl>`.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Because `Optionddl` is not something can be converted to a `List`.
Consider this:

```
List<Optionddl> oddl = q.ADDLOption.Split(new string[]{'|'}).ToList<Optionddl>();
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not compile. `char` cannot be implicitly converted to `string`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can create some implicit/explicit operators :

```
public class Optionddl
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator string(Optionddl option)
    {
        return option.text + "," + option.value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Optionddl(string str)
    {
        string[] extracted = str.Split(",");
        return new Optionddl { text = extracted[0], value = extracted[1] };
    }
}
```

This way you can make something like :

```
Optionddl meOption = new Optionddl { value = "IE", text = "IE" };
string meOptionString = meOption; // result of meOptionString = "IE,IE"
meOption = meOptionString; // result of meOption = { text = "IE", value = "IE" }
```